# Colpitts Oscillator schematic to breadboard implementation

Tags: oscillator, schematics

I'm starting to learn electronics as a hobby. I'm trying to take a schematic of a Colpitts Oscillator and implement it on a breadboard. I'm using the example found here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/colpitts.html I'm trying to implement it on a breadboard using Tinkercad circuits before I physically wire it up on a breadboard. No matter what I do I cannot get it to work. When I click the simulate button in tinkercad the voltage on the supply goes up for a brief second and then drops to zero. The osciloscope does not show any output. I'm not sure if I'm correctly translating the schematic to the breadboard. Any help would be appreciated. Below is a screenshot of tinkercad:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this simulator.  http://tinyurl.com/y82e68dk  Many pre-loaded designs or modify with right mouse, add scope trace etc.  All parts are considered ideal.

Answer (score 2):

All the holes a,b,c,d,e in a row are connected together. All the holes f,g,h,i,j in a row are connected together.

So if we look at rows 4, 11, and 15 in your image, we can see that the capacitors are short-circuited.

You need to do the layout again bearing in mind which holes are already connected.

Comment: So I think that's part of my confusion. The schematic shows the capacitors are connected together so I put them on the same row and added wires to make them connected. How are they supposed to be connected?

Answer (score 0):

Most plastic versions of 2N2222 (often labeled PN2222) have pin-out like this:
[image: PN2222]

Your tinkercad looks backwards, or upside-down.